# unable to create variable tensor by passing numpy value as input with custom shape

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

```
numpy_A=np.arange(1,25,dtype=np.int32)
output:
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24], 
 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

1.create constant tensor by passing numpy value as input with custom shape

```
constant_tensor_diff_shape=tf.constant(numpy_A,shape=(3,4,2))
output:
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 4, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 3,  4],
        [ 5,  6],
        [ 7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10],
        [11, 12],
        [13, 14],
        [15, 16]],
```

1.create variable tensor  by passing numpy value as input with custom shape  throws error , kindly let me know why this error is not being thrown when creating constant tensor . not able to find any documentation in tensorflow website as well .

```
varaible_tensor_diff_shape=tf.Variable(numpy_A,shape=(3,4,2))

ValueError: In this `tf.Variable` creation, the initial value's shape ((24,)) is not compatible with the explicitly supplied `shape` argument ((3, 4, 2)).
```

Comment: The docs say: "The Variable() constructor requires an initial value for the variable, which can be a Tensor of any type and shape. This initial value defines the type and shape of the variable. After construction, the type and shape of the variable are **fixed**. The value can be changed using one of the assign methods". And furthermore: "The shape argument to Variable's constructor allows you to construct a variable with a **less** defined shape than its initial_value". A less defined shape in your case would be `None` but not `(3,4,2)` which is fully defined.

Comment: thanks i read the documentation as well its not clear on what they mean by "A less defined shape in your case would be None but not (3,4,2) which is fully defined" . why it should be none and what the problems with (3,4,2) ?

Comment: A less defined shape is a variable shape.. It does not have to entirely `None` , just less defined than the initial shape. `None` could represent any arbitrary dimension.

Comment: its not clear , my goal is to create a variable tensor with any valid custom shape since the numpy initial value's shape is  ((24,)) what would be the correct "less defined shape" in my case to create a tensor using numpy with  custom shape , 1 ) if you say its None then then it will create variable tensor with default shape but that not what i need so What value would i need to pass to create a any custom shape in this case ?

Comment: Just reshape your tensor to desired shape before feeding it to `tf.Variable`.

Comment: im creating a tensor for 1st time , so how can i reshape a tensor without even creating it ? varaible_tensor_diff_shape=tf.Variable(numpy_A,shape=(3,4,2))

Comment: thanks for the answer in chatroom , below code that you shared about variable types
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

numpy_A=np.arange(1,25,dtype=np.int32)
varaible_tensor_diff_shape=tf.Variable(numpy_A.reshape((3, 4, 2)))
print(type(varaible_tensor_diff_shape))
print(type(tf.expand_dims(varaible_tensor_diff_shape,-1)))
  
after reshaping, you no longer have a tf.Variable
<class 'tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops.ResourceVariable'>
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>